# Is there a common notation for a matrix with one entry equal to one and zero otherwise?

Tags: notation

Kind of like a unit vector, but it's a matrix.

For example, if the notation is $A_{ij}$, then this matrix has all zero elements, except $a_{ij} = 1$.

Is there a common notation/term for this kind of matrix?

The goal is to write something like: for a matrix $B$, then $B + A_{12}$ gives the same matrix but one element at $(1,2)$ is incremented.

Is there a better notation for this goal?

Thanks!

Comment: I have seen $e_{12}$

Comment: Such matrices form a basis of matrices as a vector space

Comment: The Wikipedia article [Single-entry matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-entry_matrix) uses $J^{ij}$ notation but I have not seen it before. More common is [Elementary matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_matrix) $L_{ij}(1) = I_n +J^{ij}.$ Another choice is $e_i\otimes e_j^* = J^{ij}$ using [tensor product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_product).

Comment: I have seen and used $E_{12}$.

Comment: @Somos Ah neat, didn't find this article! Although the article itself admits the name (and possibly notation) is "not common" haha

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use any letter you want to use for a single-entry matrix, as long as you define it, but $e$ is a nice choice (e.g., $e_{12}$), since $e$ is often used for basis vectors, and the single-entry matrices form a basis of matrices as a vector space.

Comment: This is what I had thought too, although matrices are commonly capitalized. However since basis vectors don't appear in the text this is a good choice. Thanks!

Comment: This notation is reasonably common in the literature, too. See, e.g., p. 2 of Humphrey's *Introduction to Lie Algebras and Representation Theory*.